# How to use the table function conditioned on another variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to use the `table` function to check how many people are at different levels of education in each year. The variable education is a factor variable with 3 categories (1, low, 2, mid, 3 high).

I tried this code:  `df %>% group_by(year) %>% table(education)`. However, it did not work. I know that i could use the function `select` for each year, but that would be too long. Is there a shorter way, could someone guide me please?

```
year    education
2004    1
2004    2
2004    1
2005    2
2005    2
2005    3
2006    1
2006    3
2006    3


structure(list(year = structure(c(2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2006, 2006, 2006), format.stata = "%9.0g"), education = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `aggregate` and `table`, which requires no additional package beyond Base R:

```
aggregate(dat, by=list(dat$year), table)

#>   Group.1 year education.1 education.2 education.3
#> 1    2004    3           2           1           0
#> 2    2005    3           0           2           1
#> 3    2006    3           1           0           2
```

Here is a solution using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, .N, by=.(year, education)]
#>    year education N
#> 1: 2004         1 2
#> 2: 2004         2 1
#> 3: 2005         2 2
#> 4: 2005         3 1
#> 5: 2006         1 1
#> 6: 2006         3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`table` applies to atomic vectors.  For your case, you should use `count`

```r
df %>%
  count(year, education)
```